# Is there a way to use a global variable for the whole npm project?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

I need to use a variable between node modules folder and src folder.Is there a way to use a variable to be used within the whole project?
Thanks.

Comment: as a very first line in your project `process.variableName = something` ?

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure why you'd need this variable to be accessed within node_modules

Comment: I have used a package which has some style variables, which i want to change for anyone getting it from github.

Comment: style variables as in less/sass/scss or JS variables that control styling?

Comment: js variable or anything so that everyone can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is done with [process environment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). Any project can look for a common environment variable and handle that case accordingly, as well as the node modules of said project. As long as they agree on the name, they all share the same environment. Have a good default, don't force people to set this environment variable.

The environment can be set using an [environment file](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) (do not check this into source control!), on your container or cloud configuration, or even right on the command line itself.

```
TLOG=info npm test
```

That is an example that I use frequently. My project runs logging for the test cases only at `alert` level - there are a lot of tests so it makes the output less verbose. However, sometimes while developing I want to see all the logs, so my project is looking for an environment variable `TLOG` (short for "test logging") and I can set it *just for that run!* Also no code change is needed, which is nicer than JavaScript variables that need to be set back to original values, forget to be turned off, etc.